# IIS7.5 - (413) Request Entity Too Large

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, iis-7.5

I've seen all similar questions but it didn't help me.

I have a WCF application that works as Windows Service. Also I have a asp.net mvc5 site that works against IIS 7.5.

And as it's clear from title I get 413 response when try to upload files with summary size more than 10Mb.

My WCF host has following TCP bindings:

```
var tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding
                {
                    ReliableSession = { InactivityTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 12, 0, 0) },
                    MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue,
                    MaxBufferPoolSize = Int32.MaxValue,
                    CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0),
                    ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0),
                    SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0),
                    TransferMode = TransferMode.StreamedResponse,
                    ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
                    {
                        MaxDepth = Int32.MaxValue,
                        MaxArrayLength = Int32.MaxValue,
                        MaxBytesPerRead = Int32.MaxValue,
                        MaxNameTableCharCount = Int32.MaxValue,
                        MaxStringContentLength = Int32.MaxValue
                    }
                };
```

My WCF connector (in web site) has following bindings:

```
NetTcpBinding
            {
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue,
                MaxBufferPoolSize = Int32.MaxValue,
                CloseTimeout = timeout5Min,
                ReceiveTimeout = timeout5Min,
                OpenTimeout = timeout5Min,
                SendTimeout = timeout5Min,
                TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed,
                ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
                {
                    MaxDepth = Int32.MaxValue,
                    MaxArrayLength = Int32.MaxValue,
                    MaxBytesPerRead = Int32.MaxValue,
                    MaxNameTableCharCount = Int32.MaxValue,
                    MaxStringContentLength = Int32.MaxValue
                }
            };
```

I set this in IIS configuration in applicationHost.config file:

```
<location path="Site">
        <system.webServer>
            <serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="20971520" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
```

I have following settings in Web.config file of web site:

```
<requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="20971520" />
</requestFiltering>
```

But I still have 413 response.
Locally it works fine with IIS Express. For this reason I'm almost sure that deal is in IIS 7.5 rather than in configuration of WCF host.

Please give me ideas how to troubleshoot it:).

UPD.
Code of host:

```
string address = "net.tcp://localhost:8001/WcfService";
var wcfService = new WcfService();
ServiceHost _svcHost = new ServiceHost(wcfService, new Uri[] { });
var tcpBinding = (see above line "var tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding...")
_svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWcfService), tcpBinding, address);
_svcHost.Open();
```

Code of client:

```
IWcfService _service = ChannelFactory<IWcfService>.CreateChannel(GetNetTcpBinding(),
                    new EndpointAddress(String.Format("net.tcp://{0}:{1}/{2}", _hostAddress, _port, _serviceName)));
var co = (ICommunicationObject)_service;
co.Open();
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you create the service host and the client?

Comment: Please see above.

Comment: try changing transfer encoding to chunked

Comment: What do you mean? I read that TransferMode.Streamed is already chunked.